# Moving single rows in a dataGrid in flashbuilder4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flashbuilder4

Is it possible to have "Move-Up / Move-Down" buttons that can move a selected row in a dataGrid and move it to a different row in the database?

Where can I get more info or an example of this and what would this type of operation be called?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible to have "Move-Up / Move-Down" buttons that can move a selected row in a dataGrid and move it to a different row in the database?
```

Yes, but you'll have to implement those buttons yourself, along with the algorithm to change your dataProvider as those buttons are clicked.

I created a list with these sort of buttons.  We call it a [DataSorter](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=7).

Comment: Can you give any more specific details on how to do this?  I'm try to understand the process.

Comment: Create a column (or columns) with an itemRenderer that contains a button.  Have the buttons dispatch an event, make sure it bubbles.  In your event handler, modify the dataProvider accordingly.  If you want something more in depth than that, I can provide consulting services..